# Hide/Remove Wp Directory /wp-content/uploads/

Tags: directory, ftp

how do we hide /wp-content/uploads/2019/03/?

I want my url of the picture to be like pensionwebsitewi.com.au/nnovating.jpg

See SS below

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Would it not be problematic if you had same filenames in different upload folders?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress development! As your question currently is written it's unclear to us what exactly you are trying to achieve here. Hide these URL args from where? And what have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @leymannx I apologize if my question above was not clear. What I am trying to achieve is that,.. I want to hide /wp/content/uploads/2019/03/ in the url like the screenshot above. So the url should be pensionwebsitewi.com/innovating.jpg,  hide /wp/content/uploads/2019/03/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code `define('UPLOADS','')`and also unclick  Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders from media settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: sure, let me know :)

Answer (score -2):

you can certainly alter the `wp-content/uploads` and make it to appear as `/uploads` or media by adding the following code in your `wp-config.php`:

```php
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
define( ‘UPLOADS’, ”.’media’ );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I will try it tomorrow.